# Is this correct if I initialize a map attribute in bean class in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

```
public class ClassName implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, Integer> property= new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

For this above example I want to now whether it is the correct approach? Or every time while setting the value I need to check and Initialize there?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your requirement.

Comment: More info is necessary. What kind of bean? EJB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. Adding the check in setter method to check if hashmap is initialized would be overhead.

If you are concern about the memory allocation of hashmap, then you can set the initial capacity while initializing this hashmap.